# C using typedef or #define to define structure

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have question about two action performance (in any way) this question is simple but there is big question (when there are 2 ways, which one is better)
i want to create structure in C language. this are 2 options for me

**1- define this on .h file and use it in the program**

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
} myStructure;
```

**2 - use this kind of define to define this structure**

```
#define myStructure struct { int id; }
```

which way is better? i know that we use the way 1 more but i don't know why i think the second way is a mother way to **define**
please compare this ways **(performance in anyway)**

**Update 1:**

thank you for your answers. in last 2 response i got this reason that we can't use the second way if we want to use that variable in functions params. it's true but one point. we can make that function as macro function too and this solve the problem. something like this

```
#define myStructure struct { int id; }
#define FUNC(__MYSTRUCTURE)     printf("%d", __MYSTRUCTURE.id)
int main() {
myStructure var1;
var1.id = 542;
FUNC(var1);
}
```

Comment: `a mother way`..do you mean `another way`?

Comment: We don't know why you think the 2. option is another way either. Your 2. option is just nonsense and will not work.

Comment: no i mean Mother way .. (basic way)

Comment: The two are not really comparable... Why would you want to declare your struct as a macro?

Comment: that's my question ... when it's possible to declare as a macro why we shouldn't or we should do this !

Comment: @itmanwork But that question doesn't not make sense either. In this one particular case in your question, you should not do it since it will not make your program even compile. But people cannot list all the other thousands of ways you could use a #define.

Comment: @itmanwork the #define doesn't declare a type it defines a new unnamed structure every time.  Is this some sort of coding standards type question and you just need a solid answer to bash the noob on the nose with?

Comment: @itmanwork What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What's wrong with `typedef`?

Comment: So you will rewrite every single function in your code as a macro so it can handle your #define'd struct?

Comment: @itmanwork, you seem to be terribly misinformed.  There is only one way to declare a structure type, and although both of your alternatives *include* variations on it, neither presents it cleanly.  I am speaking of a `struct` declaration, which does not need to occur in the context of a `typedef`, and which is not particularly well served by being obfuscated within a macro definition.

Comment: Please deselect the answer (remove the green tick) I will delete the answer as the question is quite irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the second one is *nonsense* in many way. You don't want to do that.

The second if used only - then think how would you pass it to the function. There are innumerous problem that you would face - one of them shown below :-

```
void fun( myStructure z){
    printf("%d\n", z.id);
}

 myStructure zz;
 zz.id = 666;
 fun(zz);  <-- error over here.
```

This gives you error.

The correct choice is to use `typedef` to create a type alias of the above declared `struct` and use it.
Also the fundamental question is why would you do that. This is not the practical way to go about it.

#### Edit:

On reply to OP's edit - on my response OP responded that the problem can be overcome by specifying a macro which takes it as argument. This comes with the drawback that now debugging will be much more difficult. And for a large project this will be even harder to work with.

---

The thing is - with

```
struct {
  int id;
} a;
```

You have *declared a type*. But then in the same code if you do this

```
struct {
int id;
} b;
```

They won't be of *same type*.

And those can't be passed as a function because the *type information associated with the `struct` declared can't be used* so that we can specifically distinguish which is of what type - it is anonymous struct with no name information.

Every single time you create a type information that is not accessible to be reused later as type information is absent in the next lines because of anonymity.

From [standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20) (Proving that it indeed declaring a type)

> A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of
> member objects (and, in certain circumstances, an incomplete array),
> each of which has an **optionally specified name** and possibly distinct
> type.

Comment: please read the update

Answer (score 1):

This two ways have virtually nothing in common. For example, the following code is invalid if you use the macro version

```
myStructure *p1 = 0;
myStructure *p2 = 0;
p1 = p2; // <- Type mismatch
```

while the `typedef` version will behave "as expected". This means that you macro version does not really define a type that is in any way "reusable". It might "work" for certain niche, narrow and restricted purposes, but it's usability is nowhere near the `typedef` version.

Comment: please read update

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of performance at that level is just plain wrong. Performance issues come from bad algorithms, doing too much unnecessary work, and you usually don't optimize stuff you didn't even bother to measure.

http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 0):

A macro is just a dumb text substitution - everywhere the macro `myStructure` appears will be replaced with the text `struct { int id; }`. This is not going to be valid in contexts were a type *name* is expected (such as in a function parameter list).

This is the reason the `typedef` facility exists - it allows you to create a new type name for abstraction purposes.  It's the *right* way to accomplish what you want to do.  The macro version is trying to use a wrench as a hammer, or a screwdriver as a chisel.  It's simply the wrong tool for the job.

Performance considerations are irrelevant in this case.